# Convert 'char' type to 'int' and preserve data in C language

Tags: c, if-statement

I am currently taking a Programming Fundamentals college class that deals with the C programming language. One assignment that I have is to make a program that creates a random number from 1 to 10, and has the user guess the number. The problem I am having is that I have to use the `isdigit()` function to check that the guess is a number. I have used

```
scanf("%c", &userChar);
```

to store the argument to check that the guess is a digit in the following manner:

```
if isdigit(userChar)
```

However, I want to check to make sure that the number is between 1 and 10 by converting 'userChar' to an int variable to check in the following manner:

```
if (userNum >= 1 && userNum <= 10)
```

I have not yet learned how to do this so I was hoping someone from this site could help me. Also, I need it to check whether or not the user guessed the right number. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add more info about what datatype is `userChar` and whether it contains int values, numeric values declared as char, or `'0' - '9'` or `"1" - "10"`

Comment: Do you have to use %c or can you use %d?

Comment: A single `char` cannot represent the 2 characters needed for "10". If you want to keep the input a single character, you better review how you are going accept "1 to 10".

Comment: To prevent Undefined Behaviour from `isdigit()` (in case the user types something like `"ΔЙ๗あ叶葉말"`) remember to cast the value to `unsigned char`: `isdigit((unsigned char)value)`

Comment: Well, I was using the char type for userChar because in my college book, it saaid that the char type is needed to use the isdigit() function. So far, I am kinda confused about C. I feel more comfortable with python, but it isn't one of the languages offered through my college

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since 10 cannot be stored in a single character, you would either need to use two digits, or to ask the user to guess a number from 0 to 9, inclusive.

To make an `int` from a single-digit character use this code snippet:

```
int digitVal = charDigit - '0';
```

This works, because digits 0 through 9 are located next to each other in the ASCII encoding: the code for `1` equals the code for `0` plus one; the code for `2` equals the code for `0` plus two, and so on. Therefore, when you subtract the code of `0` (which is denoted as `'0'` in C) from a single-digit character, you get the integer value of the corresponding digit.

Comment: *Only* in ASCII-compatible encodings. This is not a requirement in the C standard--EBCDIC, for instance, does not arrange digits like this.

Comment: @JonathanGrynspan: it is a requirement ([EBCDIC has all digits sequential](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC)). If a character set doesn't have all digits sequential, a C implementation for that must translate the "hardware" digits to a sequential representation.

Comment: This is news to me. Is there some place in the C standard it says that? (Also d'oh! on the EBCDIC.)

Comment: @JonathanGrynspan: see the [5.2.1 in C99 Standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#5.2.1).

Comment: Note that there is no similar requirement for letters (which in fact are not contiguous in EBCDIC).

Comment: Ack, you're right. Brainfart--I was thinking of the `x - 'A'` problem.

Answer (score 1):

In C the `char` type is an integral type and you can do arithmetic operations with them. You can convert between different integral types using casts - a type name in ()'s, e.g. to convert a `char` `userChar` to a `long` you can write `(long)userChar`. However in integer expressions types smaller than `int` are promoted to `int`, so you can don't need a cast to convert a `char` to an `int`.

The last thing that you need to know is that whatever the integer equivalent of the character `'1'` is (the actual value is unimportant) it is 1 more than the integer equivalent for `0`; in other words the characters `'0'`, `'1'`, ..., `'9'` are represented by a contiguous range of integers (and the same is true for `'a'`, `'b'`, ..., `'z'` and `'A'`, `'B'`, ..., `'Z'`).

Therefore if you know a `char` is a digit (e.g. because you've used `isdigit()`) you get it's integer equivalent using:

```
int intValue = userChar - '0';
```

Comment: Although you are 100% right about digits occupying a contiguous range of codes, C standard does not have the same requirement for letters. Although chances of encountering [EBSDIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC) these days are relatively slim, it is an example of a valid encoding of C characters in use today that does not place letters in a contiguous range.

Comment: @dasblikenlight - yes, I glossed over EBCDIC as its unlikely to be an issue these days. Sounds that, like me, you can remember it. And of course there was more than one variant of EBCDIC...

Answer (score 0):

The digits, in C, are '0', '1', ..., '9' and they are sequential.
`char`s are just small `int`s, so `userChar - '0'` (assuming userChar has a `char` with a value between `'0'` and `'9'`) has a value of `0` to `9`.

You can use that to validate the input.

Comment: Yes it is. C digits representations are sequential. `'0' + 3 == '3'` always.

Comment: @JonathanGrynspan it is. (C99, 5.2.1p3) "In both the source and execution basic character sets, the value of each character after 0 in the above list of decimal digits shall be one greater than the value of the previous."

Answer (score 0):

So you need to accept the user's input of an integer that could be anywhere from 1 to 10.

You *could* read a single character at a time and compute the value; for example, if the user enters `'1'` followed by `'0'`, you need to compute the integer value `10` from those two characters.  You should have enough information to be able to do that.

But the usual way to do that is to use a library function to read a value directly (but see below)  into an `int` object.  (Hints: `scanf`, `"%d"`; read your documentation.)  With that approach, all the calculation is done by the appropriate library function, and there's no need for you to call `isdigit()` yourself.

Library functions like `scanf` are defined to work, in effect, by calling `getchar()` repeatedly, reading single characters and assembling the needed information in some way.  You can do all that work yourself, or you can let `scanf` do it for you.  Which you should do depends on the exact requirements of your assignment; if the point of the assignment is to figure out how to do what `scanf` does, then of course just calling `scanf` wouldn't be acceptable.